# TypeError: dict object is not callable (inside Thread function)

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error in a program which is using *threading* to perform functions simultaneously, this process is a  job which is run once per hour, The data that comes in is from a view in sql.

The function that is called in target *arg* returns a dictionary and says
"dict object is not callable".
Inside the function, is returned a dictionary.
My doubt is what should return in this function, if I don't return anything will it affect any other thread?

```
# inside the jobs in django I call this function
def ticket_booking():  
  
    query = " SELECT * FROM vw_ticket_list;"  

    ttd = []
    try:
        result = query_to_dicts(query)
        tickets = json.loads(to_json(result))
        if tickets:

            # Calling the vaccination push message (php).
            for ticket in tickets:
            
                # Getting Generic details used by all categories
                full_name = tickets['full_name'] 
                gender = tickets['gender']  
                email =tickets[email]

                if tickets['language_id'] == 1:  # book english movie tickets 
                   
                    # Calling the function inside the Thread for a Syncronuz Call (Wait and Watch)
                    myThread = threading.Thread(target=book_english(email, full_name))
                    myThread.start()  
                    myThread.join()  

                if tickets['language_id']  == 2:  # book italian movie tickets 
                    myThread = threading.Thread(target=book_italian( email, full_name, gender))
                    myThread.start()  # Starting the Thread
                    myThread.join() #Will return here if sth is returned
```

As you can see in code comments, if book italian function returns sth, only then it can return here and I have 5 threads in total to excute simultaneously, book italian function is like:

```
def book_italian(email,fullname,gender):
try
    # posts data to another server #
    b=requests.post(some postdata)

     a =log.objects.create(log data from b in crct format)
     return a--->{"Message":"Log created successfully"}
```

a is type class dict and I tried to change it to many types still gives me same error, this job isn't running when run in crontab.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please also provide a traceback.

Comment: Note that `try` blocks should be reserved only for code that can potentially fail. Don't put all your logic inside a `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `threading.Thread` to execute something, you should separate the `target` callable object (like a function) and corresponding `arguments` (parameters) then pass them respectively:

```py
myThread = threading.Thread(target=book_italian, args=(email, full_name, gender))
```

Refer to [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).